# How to delete from a particular string to end to the end of the paragraph in groovy

Tags: java, regex, string, groovy

I have this paragraph that starts with **Feel free to reply to this email...**, I want to replace everything from this point that is from Feel free to reply to this email.. to the end to the end of the paragraph with an empty string. I have taken a look at the following but it seems not to work:

```
replaceAll
String s = replaceAll("Feel free to reply to this email..", " ") //this was not helpful since I need to know the complete text that I want to replace.
```

Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you really just use `replace`, `replaceAll` or `replaceFirst` with no arguments? Surely, it would fail.

Comment: I want to keep on the text before  "Feel free to reply to this email.." and delete replace any other text after it with  "Feel free to reply to this email.." included with an empty string.

Comment: Try the regex `"Feel free to reply to this email\.\..*"`

Comment: In Groovy, use `String result = s.replaceAll(/Feel free to reply to this email\.\.\..*(?:\R.+)*/, "")`

Comment: It seems not to be working as expected


`String s = "Feel free to reply to this email if you have any further questions or concerns. Take Care! agent.first_name tengen Tehdw Customer Care ww.peteryou.com #tenengpeter" `

`String t = s.replaceAll(/Feel free to reply to this email\.\.\..*(?:\R.+)*/, "")`

After executing this, it prints the statement unchanged.

Comment: That's because you don't have an ellipsis in this one, but you do in your question. Add an ellipsis to your input, or remove it from your regex, and it'll work fine. For example, you could just do `Feel free to reply to this email.*`

Comment: You do not have any paragraphs, just one single paragraph text and [it works](https://ideone.com/nf8HQk). Depends on what the fixed string is that you need to start removing from.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is exactly the issue I am trying to solve, I have newlines (\n) in the paragraph. So how can I escape these newlines?

Comment: You do not need to escape newlines. Why do you think you need to escape newlines? **Use `.replaceAll(/Feel free to reply to this email.*(?:\R.+)*\R?/, "")`**. Replace `Feel free to reply to this email` with the text you need to match from and to the end of the paragraph. A paragraph is a piece of text between start/end of text and a blank line. A blank line is a double+ line break sequence.

Comment: This is what I am talking about:

`String s = "this is the text before\n\nFeel free to reply to this email if you have any further questions or concerns.\n\nTake Care! agent.first_name Vince tenege Customer Care ww.teneges.com #tenege"

when I do a `replaceAll` on this, it only removes all the text before the newline, but I want it to remove everything. what @WiktorStribiżew demonstrated [here](https://ideone.com/nf8HQk)

Comment: Ok. Now I see. So it is even easier, you need `.replaceFirst(/(?s)Feel free to reply to this email.*/, "")`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/hYMfNQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex with `replaceFirst`:

```
(?s)Feel free to reply to this email.*
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/hYMfNQ)

The `(?s)Feel free to reply to this email.*` pattern matches `Feel free to reply to this email` first and then `.*` matches all the rest of the text due to `(?s)` embedded flag option that makes `.` match any char including line break chars that `.` does not match by default.